# ToggleClass if body has css inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page that uses this code:

```
<body style="background-image:url("http://...")">
<div class="g1-body-inner"></div>
</div>
```

And others that dont have body style.

Using Jquery i want that only if body has background-image as inline style, add a new class to the div.

I've searched and tried and tried and nothing works...
Whatever code i try the result is always true (toggleclass is added).

I've tried the following codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
if ($('body').css('background-image').length != null)  { 
    $('.g1-body-inner').toggleClass("anuncio-cheio");
  }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
var $el = $('body[style*="background-image"]');
  if ( $el.length > 0 ) {
     $('.g1-body-inner').toggleClass("anuncio-cheio");
}
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
if ($( "body[style!='background-image']" ))  { 
    $('.g1-body-inner').toggleClass("anuncio-cheio");
  }
});
```

Can anybody help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to use some string validation instead something like this

```
var style = $('body').attr('style');

if(style){
   if (style.search('background') > -1){
      //It has background inline style
   } else {
    //It doesn't have background inline style
   }      

} else {
   //It doesn't have inline style
}
```

Comment: Hi ddiestra,

Thank you for your time.
Your code doesnt seem to work.

This is what i have:

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   var style = $("body").attr("style");
   if (style.search("background-image") > -1) {
     $(".g1-body-inner").toggleClass("anuncio-cheio");
   }
});

Actually this code breaks the page where the code applies to.

Comment: Hi Peter, if you see the code there is an extra if before the if with the style.search, that is because there is a case where the body will not have an inline style and the value of the variable style will be null, without that initial if you are running null.search() that will throw you an error and break your js

Comment: I created a fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/wxccv6wr/6/

Your code works. So i checked my Wordpress website jquery version which was 1.3, i updated to the latest stable version 3.3.1 and still not working.
The alert on the fiddle is correct. On my website is "undefined".

Do you happen to know why?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter, probably, I am not sure, but probably your body style is added using js, after the code I send your run, can you provide with the link of your wordpress site to check

Comment: Hi.

Thank you so much for your help.

When you said that the body style could beeing added using js it got me thinking. The background-image is added using an ads plugin (full-page), so i added the jquery not the head, but to the footer when page was already loaded and now the alert (and code) works fine.

I have another problem that the image is not showing although it's in the code, but that i will talk to the developer of the plugin.

I think i couldn't get there without yout hints, so thank you very much for your time ddiestra!

Regards